# Integrating an external code processing tool to the RAD Studio IDE

Tags: delphi, ide, c++builder, external-tools

Early Borland IDEs (TP, TC) has a mean to execute an external tool, process its output via *filter* and present an user navigable view with messages associated with corresponding file name and line/column number (protocol has been described [here](https://collab.firelab.org/software/projects/lidar/repository/revisions/59/entry/Lidar/BP/UNITS/EXAMPLES/UTILS/GREP2MSG.PAS)).
Is there a support for such kind of integration nowadays or I have to resort something like `IOTAMessageServices.AddToolMessage` (and write such "fitting" myself)?